# How to execute a my sql migration script in MYSQL Shell?

Tags: mysql, shell

Despite a comprehensive search I couldnt find a definite answer how to run a mysql script, sitting in one specific directory, directly in the mysql shell.

The MYSQL documentation states: 
shell> mysql < text_file

So far so good, but the text file (*.sql) sits in another directory than the mysql instance. So that doesnt work that easily - unfortunately...

I hope someone can help me out.

Thank you in advance

GG

Answer (score 5):

In the documentation you are quoting, "shell>" refers to a Unix prompt, not MySQL shell.

In MySQL shell, just do "source /path/to/file" "/path/to" being the absolute path to the file.

Comment: Thanks Tristan, yes, thats what I found out myself after studying the documentation deeper :-)

Comment: You can also use this from the shell, with the absolute path, like `mysql < /path/to/text_file.sql`

Answer (score 0):

So found it out myself ;-)

Just add the source path of the script behind the mysql-Prompt like:

mysql> SOURCE C:\User\Folder\Folder...

Best GG

Comment: Nice, I suggest you delete this answer and validate mine from yesterday though  ;)